# how to show attributes in a main method xml file

Tags: xml-parsing

I'm doing a command line interface and I'm trying to show the account attributes and list of addresses but it just compiles. I think I'm doing something wrong but I cant find it.

```
if (entity.equalsIgnoreCase("account")) {
    //if the user types in show account a list of 
    //addresses and the attributes from account
    //should print out
    for (Address ad: adList) {
        if (te.equalsIgnoreCase(a.getAccountNumber())) {
            System.out.println("type: " + ad.getType());
            System.out.println("Account:");
            System.out.println(c.getMailingAddress().getAccount().getAddresses());
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: when I run the code. I"ll type in show account and enter the number and then nothing happens. it just says build successful

Comment: you must show more code, and what xml you parse.